# Java WebStart - How do I solve a NoSuchMethodError runtime?

Tags: java, netbeans, crash, java-web-start, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting some NoSuchMethodErrors runtime error in my Java Web Start application, I'm using Netbeans 7.3. At compile time everything seems Ok; but when I launch Java Mission Control it shows some of these errors during application startup.

How can I fix them?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Error.<init>(String)
java.lang.LinkageError.<init>(String)
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError.<init>(String)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.<init>(String)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Class)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(Class)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$100(Class)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run()
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$1.run()
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID()
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass,Class,ClassNotFoundException, ObjectStreamClass)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(boolean)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(boolean)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(boolean)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(boolean)  
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()  
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ObjectInputStream)   
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[])  
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])   
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Object, ObjectInputStream)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Object, ObjectStreamClass) 
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(boolean)   
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(boolean)  
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()  
...
```

All of them are related to readObject (ObjectInputStream) method.

Thank you.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the stack trace and more information on what you are calling, please.

Comment: `jasef2.cs.ObjectSreamingManager.unzip(InputStream)` It appears the applet is trying to load a native(?) which is not on the run-time class-path of the applet. Either that or the native it is getting is out of date.. (I might be way off in that!)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I found that all NoSuchMethodErrors come from a reaObject (ObjectInputStream) method.
When I read a particular Object (such as ArrayLists, Lists or objects from a user-defined class) there is a NoSuchMethodError.
Instead when I read normal Objects like String, Object, Integer, etc, there aren't Errors! Maybe i'm doing something wrong with serialization.

Comment: *"..or objects from a user-defined class"* Does it declare `implements Serializable`? An `ArrayList` should be serializable so long as all objects it contains are also serializable. Have a close read of [Serializable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) (& stop trying to 'code by magic' which *never* works).

Comment: I will. But do you think that a bad serialization \ deserialization could be the cause of those errors ?